# Different behaviour between javac 1.6 and javac 1.7 when handling special characters

Tags: java, encoding, java-7

first of all I would like to thank you and to explicitly say that I've been slamming my head on this issue for several days and looking for a solution in other similar threads with no success.

Our application is responsible of generating java classes and some of them may contain special characters in the class name (thus file name) such as ZoneRéservée435.java forcing the encoding to be UTF-8.

Till Java 1.6 the ant task:

```
<javac source="1.5" target="1.5" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" deprecation="on" debug="on" classpathref="classpath" fork="false" memoryMaximumSize="512m" encoding="UTF-8">
```

worked fine.

When moved to java 1.7 the fileName was not getting saved using the UTF-8 encoding resulting in a file name similar to: ZoneRe?serve?e435.java

Looking around I came to understand that I needed to set the env variable LC_CTYPE to UTF-8.
That solved the fileName issue but I still get a compilation error

```
error: class ZoneRéservée435 is public, should be declared in a file named ZoneRéservée435.java
```

Although they have the same name, they seem to be encoded in two different ways.
The interesting part is that this difference of encoding was happening with java 1.6 but was compiling fine.

Does anyone have any suggestion or ideas?

For what I came to understand the encoding issue is related to the fact that the class is generated with the following:

```
 Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

- The code inside the file is using U+00E9 to define the special char;
- The file name uses eU+0301;

Any suggestion on how to deal with this?

Comment: I would also like to add the fact that I have the file.encoding and sun.jnu.encoding all set to UTF-8

Comment: Is your old name file also exisiting? If yes, that will cause the issue. Delete that.

Comment: Hum no the directory containing the generated sources is getting deleted and generated every time. Same applies with the compiled code

Comment: @MaLLinok: *(not an answer to your question hence the comment)*...  For what it's worth we've got build scripts that are designed to fail instantly if they detect any file (not just *.java* files) whose name contains non-ASCII characters.  Too many issues on various OSes, with various scripts failing, etc.  Actually it's even more restrictive than that: we only allow a subset of printable ASCII chars.  Lots of people find such a guideline and a script actually enforcing it to be too restrictive but at least for us issues like the one you're describing simply cannot happen.

Comment: @MaLLinok Does this problem occur on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your file system uses the decomposed form of the letter `é` (which is the sequence of the characters `e` and `´` or `\u0065` and `\u0301`) while your code generator uses the composed form of `é` (which is `\u00e9`). This is a typical problem on Apple's HFS+ file system, which always uses the decomposed form.

What you can do to solve this problem is modify your application to decompose the class name that appears in the generated source file with `java.text.Normalizer`:

`Normalizer.normalize(classname, Normalizer.Form.NFD)`

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence