# Java SE 1.7 ClassDefNotFound

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I currently switch from java 1.6 to 1.7 and found out that my code would not run because of ClassDefNotFound exception. The exceptions are all raised on classes with UTF8 class names(chinese characters to be specific). Does anyone know why java 1.7 lost support for non-english character class and package names?

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: badstudent/mappings/北京/北京Mappings
    at badstudent.mappings.AllProvinceMappings.initMappings(AllProvinceMappings.java:42)
    at badstudent.mappings.MappingBase.<init>(MappingBase.java:22)
    at badstudent.mappings.AllProvinceMappings.<init>(AllProvinceMappings.java:38)
    at badstudent.common.Constants.<clinit>(Constants.java:24)
    at badstudent.mappings.MappingManager.getProvinceMappings(MappingManager.java:18)
    at badstudent.mappings.MappingManager.getAllCity(MappingManager.java:46)
    at badstudent.dao.test.SpeedTest.javaAllCity(SpeedTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: badstudent.mappings.北京.北京Mappings
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: Can you post the error trace here?

Comment: have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588940/different-behaviour-between-javac-1-6-and-javac-1-7-when-handling-special-charac

Comment: This is the exact scenario I code in English all the time - though it's not my native language...

Comment: All my classes are created by hand. The exceptions are raised when I am trying to import or call the class.

Comment: What is the encoding of the .java file that's attempting to perform the import?

Comment: Every file in the project is encoded as UTF-8

Comment: Can you try a simpler project? For example, just two Java classes. I just have a try, it works.

Comment: I tried with two classes it still does not work with Java 1.7

Comment: Would you please describe the details? Just use command line or use eclipse?

Comment: So i have a simple class called 北京Mappings and I am trying to run it in eclipse. Then the error comes out:"Error: Could not find or load main class ������Mappings" The error won't occur if I am in java 1.6

Comment: 1, check your ide's default encoding: Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding; 2, check your Java running configuration: Run Configurations -> select the one you use -> select Common tab -> Encoding.

Comment: Please also try to get JVM file.encoding property via running a simple Java program in eclipse: System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());

Comment: Both encoding have been set to UTF8 and running the above commend gives me "UTF-8"

Comment: It is a strange issue. How do you switch JDK? And what is your eclipse IDE's encoding (check eclipse.ini).

Comment: where can I find eclipse.ini? I download the JDK from oracle.

Comment: eclipse.ini is in eclipse installation folder. Please also try to run the class from command line to check whether it is a JDK problem or not.

Comment: running from command line is fine. So i suspect its an eclipse issue. But as far as I switch jre version back to 1.6 it will run on eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean it won't work if you run eclipse with JDK 7 and it works if you run eclipse with JDK 6?

Comment: Yes, but I am switching JRE System Library version

Comment: Is there any exception in eclipse's log file (in your workspace diretory -> .metadata -> .log)?

Comment: There is a bunch of errors called "Problems encountered while deleting resources." but I believe that does not effect the problem.

Comment: Check you JDK 7 and JDK 6 library configuration. Preferences -> Installed JRE -> Edit. Is there any default VM argument set?

Comment: Neither of them has anything

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26049/discussion-between-lhuang-and-michael-yuzhiheng-xiao)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the script
Make sure to find your own JAVA_HOME and LAUNCHER_JAR path

```
#!/bin/sh
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0_15.jdk/Contents/Home
LAUNCHER_JAR=/Applications/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-   1813.jar

java \
-showversion \
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m \
-Xms1024m \
-Xmx1024m \
-Xdock:icon=/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/Resources/Eclipse.icns \
-XstartOnFirstThread \
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts \
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 \
-jar $LAUNCHER_JAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there have been enhancements in Java 1.7, but nothing related to removing support to UTF-8 - see
[Internationalization Enhancements in Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.7.html) for more information.

Which environment are you using? I am using Eclipse and, when attempting saving a class with a Chinese character, I get the following error:

[image: Error in Eclipse]

--

In any case, as per Oracle's [documentation on Charsets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html):

> *Every instance of the Java virtual machine has a default charset,
>   which may or may not be one of the standard charsets. The default
>   charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and typically
>   depends upon the locale and charset being used by the underlying
>   operating system.*

As far as I can see, the default for Java 1.7 is CP-252 (for Windows) or MacRoman (for Mac), which could explain the reason for the problems you're getting.

You can use the following to find out the encoding being used in your system:

```
System.getProperty("sun.jnu.encoding");
```

I suggest you also attempt the following to make sure your system is set to use UTF-8 accordingly:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

Hopefully the above will help, but if not then a few other things to look at would be:

1. If you change your environment back to 1.6, does that fix the problem?
2. Are you getting exactly the same errors when trying to compile any of the classes with Chinese characters?
3. Are the Chinese characters the only pattern between the classes that have this problem?

Good luck!

Comment: I fixed the problem. The cause is i am on an Mac environment and Java1.7 on Mac is made by Oracle so there is an issue that eclipse can not recognize 1.7 on start up. I had a little script that will force eclipse to load java1.7 on start up but the script needs to be modified based on different environment. message me if you need the script.

Comment: @MichaelYuzhihengXiao could you post and accept your solution?